# Simplify Summation $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{8n} (-1)^\frac{(k)(k+1)(k+2)}{6}(k)^2+\sum_{k=1}^{8n}(-1)^\frac{(k+2)(k+3)}{2} (k)^2-4\sum_{k=1}^{8n}(8k-2)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{8n} (-1)^\frac{(k)(k+1)(k+2)}{6} (k)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{8n} (-1)^\frac{(k+2)(k+3)}{2} (k)^2 -4\sum_{k=1}^{8n} (8k-2)^2$$

then the value of $-S_{40}$ is equal to?

Simplifying all 3 Summations for $n = 1$ gives:

Series 1 $= -(1)^2+(2)^2+(3)^2+(4)^2-(5)^2+(6)^2 + (7)^2 + (8)^2$

Series 2 $= (1)^2+(2)^2-(3)^2-(4)^2+(5)^2+(6)^2 - (7)^2 - (8)^2$

Series 3 $= -4[(6)^2+(14)^2+(22)^2+(30)^2+(38)^2+(46)^2 + (54)^2 + (62)^2]$

This leaves us with $2(2)^2$ and $2(6)^2$ from the first two Summations.

For Series 3, I simplified using $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r$ and $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2$ formulae, giving
$\sum_{r=1}^{n}T_r = -4[\sum64r^2 - 32r + 4]$
This gives me $-47744$, and the sum of $2(2)^2$ and $2(6)^2$ gives $80$, making the net sum for $n = 1$ as $-47664$.

Hence, for $-S_{40}$, the sum should be $-5*-47664$ which is $238320$.

But the correct answer is $102400$.

Where am I going wrong? Is there an error in my logic or calculations, or in the concept itself?

Edit: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09glb.png) is the full question for those wondering, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLl6.png) is the answer given.

I could not make any sense of it, so I was asking users for their view on the question.

Comment: Why is the value of $-S_{40}$ five times the value of the sum for $n=1$? You also seem to use $S_n$ for two different things.

Comment: Made the changer regarding $S_n$ now. I multiplied the total sum by 5, as each summation has an upper limit of $8n$, so when I multiplied it with 5, I assumed it would give me $S_40$, since $8 * 5 = 40$

Comment: The upper limit for each summation in $S_{40}$ is $8\cdot 40$. Further, $5S_{1} \neq S_{40} \neq S_{5}$. 

WolframAlpha shows that $-S_{40} = 2797293440$, which does not match your answer. Are you sure the question is correct?

Comment: @BongoMan What was the original problem? The summation in given form feels unnatural.

Comment: @MyMolecules. I think that I found the trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Combine the first and second sums; compute the first terms and observe that

$$\Big( (-1)^\frac{(k)(k+1)(k+2)}{6}+(-1)^\frac{(k+2)(k+3)}{2}\Big) k^2=\Big(\left(k^3+3 k\right) \bmod 4\Big)\,k^2$$

Now, use the floor and ceiling functions to compute the sum of them.

Comment: This is actually just a direct Summation simplification question. Check out the solution to this question in the post itself. No trick here, sadly. Just wanted see if anyone could figure out the solution, and explain it in a way that made sense.